# Sum some rows in Excel after connecting with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have connected MySQL to Excel and the selected table came successfully. I want to sum a column but the result shows `0`:

[image]

Comment: yes i did i have changed the format of cell to number but with no luck... same result 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are coming in as text representations of numbers. The [SUM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sum-function-0761ed42-45aa-4267-a9fc-a88a058c1a57) is returning zero because it is summing text, not true numbers. You will note the 'number's' left cell alignment. True numbers default to right alignment in Excel; text default to left alignment.

Select the full column then quickly run Data ► Data Tools ► Text-to-Columns. Opt for 🔘 Fixed Width and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>. This should be sufficient to convert any text that can actually be a number into a true number.

In VBA, you can quickly loop through each column in a data block and force the [Range.TextToColumns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) method.

```
Dim c As Long
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
        .Columns(c).NumberFormat = "General"
        .Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns(c), _
            DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
    Next c
End With
```

Note that the .TextToColumns command will error if there is absolutely nothing in the column to process. Zero-length strings are sufficient to run the command and can be turned into truly blank cells using this same method.

Comment: Thnks bro its working.. but can we do  it by default when we open excel ?

Comment: There are a number of ways to run a macro on open but you are probably better off fixing your PHP script that generates the XLS with its text-that-look-like-numbers in the first place.

Comment: Actually, php script is not running i am establish this connection using ODBC  connection. then i am select the table from excel and that table comes in excel as shown above pic.

Comment: Then you could put the whole connection and mySQL pull into a larger VBA routine and run that code I gave you as a cleanup after fresh data has been brought in. That's a but much to be a simple addition to this question. Probably better to ask another with more details and a redacted connection string. You *can* get started by recording your actions though.